# JQuery ajax call in a JS function fails on iOS but works great on Windows 10 pc

Tags: ios, ajax

Wracking my brain for quite some time on this - thought I'd ask the experts for an assist...
The gist of my code below is to call a php function (via ajax POST) that updates a MySQL table when a registration request is rejected by an administrator.

When executing in Windows 10, all works as expected. But on iOS, it throws the error alert found in the .fail function of the ajax call (`alert("A problem has occurred with your rejection at tec_regadmin. " + teststat2 + " Please copy this error and contact your abc administrator for details.");`). Also, teststat2 is displayed as [object Object] on iOS.
An additional twist - the MySQL table successfully UPDATEs to show that the request was rejected. Code snippets are below:

**JS function with embedded ajax call to ../services/ajax_reject_registrant.php:**

```
    function regreject(Select, Directory_ID, Log_In, Gender_sex, First_Name, Last_Name) {
        console.log("Made it into the regreject function");
        var jQ13 = jQuery.noConflict();
        jQ13(document).ready(function () {
        jQ13.ajax({
            cache: false,
            headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
            url: '../services/ajax_reject_registrant.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { Selected: Select, Directory: Directory_ID, Login: Log_In, Gender: Gender_sex, FirstName: First_Name, LastName: Last_Name }
        })
            .done(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                //  Get the result
                var teststat = textStatus;
                var teststat2 = jqXHR;
                console.log("ajax reject success response data = " + teststat);
                console.log("ajax reject success response text = " + teststat2);
                alert("Registrant has been disabled in the database.");
                location.reload();
                return;
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                //  Get the result
                var teststat = textStatus;
                var teststat2 = jqXHR;
                console.log("ajax reject failure response data = " + teststat);
                console.log("ajax reject failure response text = " + teststat2);
                alert("A problem has occurred with your rejection at tec_regadmin. " + teststat2 + " Please copy this error and contact your abc administrator for details.");
                location.reload();
                return;
            });
        });
    };
```

**PHP script (../services/ajax_reject_registrant.php) called from ajax:**

```
<?php
//New Registrant Reject script
//Called from tec_regadmin.php
//Last Updated 2020/12/09
if ( isset($_POST['Selected']) ) {
    require('../tec_dbconnect.php');
    include('../includes/event_logs_update.php');
    include('tec_sendmail.php');
    $Selected2 = $_POST['Selected'];
    $Directory2 = $_POST['Directory'];
    $Login2 = $_POST['Login'];
    $Gender2 = $_POST['Gender'];
    $FirstName2 = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $LastName2 = $_POST['LastName'];
    $text = array();
    $regrejectloginquery = "UPDATE " . $_SESSION['logintablename'] . " SET active = '2'" .  " WHERE login_ID = '". $Login2 . "'";
    $regrejectlogin = $mysql->query($regrejectloginquery) or die("A database error occurred when trying to reject new Registrant info into Login table. See ajax_reject_registrant.php. Error:" . $mysql->errno . " : " . $mysql->error);
    eventLogUpdate('admin_update', "Admin ID: " .  $_SESSION['user_id'], "Registrant Reject", "LoginID: " . $Login2 . " - Directory entry: " . $Directory2);

    $success = 'Reject Success';
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($success);
}
else{
    $failed = 'Reject Failed';
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($failed);
}
?>
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Any suggestions would be GREAT!
Thank you!!!

Comment: Also wanted to note that the same issue occurs on 3 different browsers in iOS - Safari; Chrome; and Edge. Also for further clarity, the error message states "A problem has occurred with your rejection at tec_regadmin. [object Object] Please copy this error and contact your abc administrator for details.". 'abc' is an obfuscated term for the service this is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]**

A PHP form is used to call the above function (regreject) and was missing an action statement (was displayed as `action=''`). By modifying the action to include *javascript:void(0);* the issue resolved itself. All I needed to do was change the action to `action="javascript:void(0);"` in the original PHP form, and now iOS is a happy camper!

The final question I will have to ponder is "WHY was this a problem with iOS??" Wonder if I'll ever find out.